# How to clear all applications data in android?

Tags: applications, cache

Hi I want to clear all applications data(preferences and sqlite) from my phone in one tap.

How can i do this? is there any app which can do this WITHOUT ROOT PERMISSION?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do factory reset under such case.

Go to Settings -> SD & Phone storage -> Factory data reset.

I don't think an app without root can do it as apps are limited in their own sandbox.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean clearing all app and user data on the phone, you can do a factory reset via Settings -> Privacy -> Factory data reset. Note that **this erases all data on the phone**, not just app data.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a fresh phone, reboot in recovery mode and select wipe data. It will format your `/cache` and `/data` partitions. Then no data will be there other than your SD card.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 1Tap cleaner : https://market.android.com/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.acc.free&hl=en . It works on non rooted devices.

EDIT:
Try [Clean Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en) . It scans the memory card for large cache file that you can delete altogether.

Comment: unluckily this only clear the cache files.I am looking for erasing data files.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant.

But if you decided to root

These are the steps

1. Root your device
2. Install xposed framework app
3. Install gravitybox module app
4. Reboot device .

Get all these downloads by google.
Just type app name and your android version.

Comment: Could you link the apps?